# Please help how to work the inequation (x-1)/(x-5)<0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am studying for college finals and I cannot solve the inequation (x-1)/(x-5)<0 using the method the professor taught us, which I have to use in the exam.

This is another inequation using said method:
[image: whiteboard with an inequation operation]

I noticed that the inequation I posted has a different symbol than the pic, but the first one is the only example of this type the professor gave us with the less than symbol.

This is how I tried to solve it:
[image: handwritten note of inequation operation]

I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference between your professors example and your example is the professors is $\frac {x+1}{x-2} > 0$.. is *GREATER* than $0$.  ANd yours is $\frac {x-1}{x-5} < 0$ .... is *LESS* than $0$.  In the professor's examply you must assume either both $x+1$ and $x-2$ are both $>0$ or both $< 0$.  In your example you must assume *ONE* of $x-1$ and $x-5$ is $>0$ and the *other* one is $< 0$.

Comment: $\frac {positive}{postive} = positive>0$... $\frac {negative}{negative} =positive >0$.... $\frac {positive}{negative} = negative < 0$.... $\frac {negative}{positive} = negative < 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember if $\frac ab < 0$ then $a$ and $b$ are "different signs".

So if $\frac {x-1}{x-5} < 0$ then either

1)  $x - 1 > 0$ and $x -5 < 0$

OR

2) $x-1 < 0$ and $x-5 > 0$.

In case 1) we have $x - 1> 0$ so $x > 1$ and $x-5 < 0$ so $x < 5$.  So $x$ is between $1$ and $5$ or $1 < x < 5$

In case 2) we have $x -1 < 0$ and $x< 1$ and $x-5> 0$ so $x > 5$. So $x$ is both less than $1$ and greater than $5$. That's impossible.

So Case 1: is the true case and $1 < x < 5$.

.....

Alternatively.  $1 < 5$ always and so $-5 < -1$ always, and $x-5 <x - 1$ always no matter what $x$ is.

So when we know that $x-1$ and $x-5$ are "different signs" we know that $x-5$ must be the negative one (because it is the smaller one) and $x -1$ must be the positive one because it is bigger.

So $x -5 < 0 < x-1$

So $x - 5 < 0$ and $x < 5$.  And $0 < x-1$ so $1 < x$.  So $1 < x < 5$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\dfrac{x-1}{x-5}<0$, that means $x-1$ and $x-5$ have opposite sign.

So $x-1<0$ and $x-5>0$

or $x-1>0$ and $x-5<0$.

Which of those is possible?

Comment: The second one?

Comment: Why did the professor grouped same signs in the pic? Does inequations with less than have different rule than greater than?

Comment: Yes, the second one is the possible one.   It looks like in the professor's example the ratio is $\mathbf >\, 0$; that means the numerator and denominator have the same sign (both positive or both negative)

Answer (score 0):

First draw a number line and place any values of $x$ that make the left equal the right exactly. This means that $(x-1)(x-5)=0$ and the solutions to this equation are $5$ and $1$.

So mark $5$ and $1$ on your number line.

Notice that your function cannot go above or below the $x$ axis (change sign) anywhere else as it would have to go through zero and the only places where your function equals zero is at $5$ and $1$.

So pick any value in each segment formed by the number line and its crossing (this means one segment is from negative infinity to $1$, the other from $1$ to $5$ and the last one from $5$ to infinity as your function will not change it’s sign on those intervals, since it doesn’t have zeros in those regions).

Now select any number in each section to see if your segment satisfies the general inequality:

For $(-\infty,1)$ select $-3$ and see that it makes our function equal to positive value which is not what we want.

Move on to section $(1,5)$ and let’s plug in $3$. It gives us $-4$ which satisfies our inequality which means that the entire region falls below the $x$ axis so we can include that region.

The final section is $(5,\infty)$ and let’s plug in $7$ which gives a positive value when plugged in and does not satisfy the general inequality.

Now notice that the values that make our function equal zero are not to be included in the answer as we want it to be below zero and equal to zero.

So $(1,5)$ is our range of values that satisfy it.

Comment: If you type `$\infty$`, you will produce $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the numbers line.

The quotient $\frac{x-1}{x-5} <0$ when:

(1) $x-1 <0$ AND $x-5 >0$

(2) $x-1 >0$ AND $x-5<0$

Identify the segment where $x-1>0$ and $x-1<0$ on the line.

Identify the segment where $x-5>0$ and $x-5<0$ on the line.

Condition (1) above is shown as the middle segment: $x \in (1,5)$.

Condition (2) above is satisfied by segments (A) and (B). However, $x$ can't be in segments (A) and (B)in the same time, it is impossible.

So $x \in (1,5)$ is your answer.

Always test few values to verify.

[image]